# Storing a URL and token in a cookie using Flask

Tags: php, html, web, flask

I trying to pick up Flask and I'm having trouble finding some information on what I'm trying to do.  I want to incorporate the flask code into HTML and use it to store a URL and Token in a cookie.

In PHP I could do something like:

```
<?php system('cgi-bin/current_user.py '.$_COOKIE['api_token'].' '.$_COOKIE['api_url']);
```

Is there a similar way of doing it in Flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, in Flask , cookie is stored as dict{'key': value} and set the cookie in response. For example:

```
@app.route('/set_cookie')  
def set_cookie():  
    response=make_response('Hello World');  
    response.set_cookie('url','url_address_here')  
    return response
```

then you cant get cookie like this:

```
@app.route('/get_cookie')  
def get_cookie():  
    name=request.cookies.get('url')  
    return name
```

or in HTML:
url.html

```
<h1>the url is {{request.cookies.get('url')}}</h1>
```

return the html template:

```
@app.route('/get_template')  
    def get_template():  
        return render_template('url.html')
```

Here is brief of cookie in Flask Documentation [Flask Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)